# How to build a quantum model of a P-N semicondctor junction?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics

Literature for quantum modelling of a semicondunctor P-N junction seems to be almost completely absent. I am wondering is it because it is too complex or the justifications provided by classical mechanics are good enough for most purposes. It seems to me that the physics of a PN junction can be understood partially through the physics of the 2D fermi Hubbard model with multiple orbitals and varying chemical potentials connected to two channels with unequal fermi sea. To add to that there are lattice vibrations and other thermal effects which contribute to it. And definitely, this is a very hard problem to solve with the current computational means available. I was wondering if anyone could kindly throw some light on this and point to relevant literature if it exists. Thanks!

Comment: You could reed a book on a semiconductor devices. For example SZE "physics of semiconductor devices". You should find answers there on on junctions